# Regex Help for Codeigniter URL Helper

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, slug

In CI `url_title()` function, it removes dots from string whereas I want to replace with `$seperator`. Here is `url_title()`'s regex replacement array.

```
$trans = array(
  '&.+?;'                 => '',
  '[^a-z0-9 _-]'          => '',
  '\s+'                   => $separator,
  '('.$q_separator.')+'   => $separator
);

$str = strip_tags($str);

foreach ($trans as $key => $val)
{
   $str = preg_replace("#".$key."#i", $val, $str);
}
```

How can I change `$trans` array so it can replace ".", "%", "+" characters with `$separator`.

Another one is "%20" returns as nothing. How to prevent it?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$trans = array(
  '&.+?;'                 => '',
  '[^a-z0-9 _-]'          => '',
  '\s+'                   => $separator,
  '('.$q_separator.')+'   => $separator,
  '\.'                    => $separator,
  '\+'                    => $separator,
  '%'                     => $separator
);
```

Comment: Thanks. For notice, it works when we put `'\.'` key before `'&.+?;` key. But it still fails when string start with `'%20 improvement` or with a string like `20%difference` turns to `20fference`.

Comment: What's your separator?

Comment: My seperator is dash '-'.

Comment: Turns out `%20` disappers because of CI's `xss_clean()` not by the function.